# ¿Cómo usar el pseudo-selector :before en el this con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero que el valor de mis switches cambie con cada click que dé, pero me arroja error, y creo que es por el pseudo-selector, ya que no forma parte del DOM.

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function()
    {
     if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
         $(this:before).css("content","A");
        }
        
        else
        {
         $(this:before).css("content","F");
        }
    });
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "A";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "A";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br><br>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los pseudo-selectores solo pueden utilizarse en strings.  Fuera de las comillas ya no es ejecutado por jQuery, sino que genera un error en javascript.  Necesitas usar la funcion `before()` asi:

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function()
    {
     if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
         $(this).next('.slider').removeClass("off");
        }
        
        else
        {
         $(this).next('.slider').addClass("off");
        }
    });
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "A";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.slider.off:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "F";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "A";
}
.slider.round.off:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "F";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider off"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br><br>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round off"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Hola @alanfcm, ¿cómo podria hacer para que el valor cambie cuando le dé click? y gracias por desaparecer el error.

Comment: No lo puedes cambiar directamente, pero puedes agregar una clase distinta y cambiarle cuando se hace click.  Ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Esa si no me la sabia, gracias por la ayuda crack ;)